# How to open two reports in a single click in OpenERP?

Tags: python, jasper-reports, odoo

I have a wizard (memory object) which selects a partner and when I click on the submit button, I need to print two reports: one report prints the sale orders related to the partner and the other report should print the partner details. I'm using jasper reports for report creation.

Comment: Do you have to use an osv_memory wizard? It looks like the old wizards could have two report states chained together.

Comment: For others who are wondering how to generate reports from osv_memory wizards, read [this Launchpad answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/116262).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible through [jasper reports](https://code.launchpad.net/openobject-jasper-reports)(dont know about whether it is possible using other reporting modules). Create the jrxml file for all the different report formats, then create another report(considered as the main report), then add all the different reports as the sub report to the detail band of the main report. Pass the data to the subreport from the main report parser. In each subreport's properties specify that each report should come in new page.